# Nvidia gtx 755 with bumblebee - Failed to initialize the NVIDIA GPU at PCI:1:0:0 - Lenovo Y410P

Tags: drivers, nvidia, lenovo, bumblebee

I installed bumblebee with nvidia-331.
I expected **optirun glmark2** to run glmark2 but I got an error.

```
$ optirun glmark2

[  785.642896] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Failed to initialize the NVIDIA GPU at PCI:1:0:0.  Please

[  785.642945] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

Lenovo Y410P

**VGA compatible controllers**

```
$ lspci | grep VGA

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 755M] (rev a1)
```

**kernal.log (part)**

```
Jan 22 16:17:49 Io kernel: [  158.189147] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:01:00.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=none
Jan 22 16:17:49 Io kernel: [  158.189256] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20130102 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 1
Jan 22 16:17:49 Io kernel: [  158.189260] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  331.38  Wed Jan  8 19:32:30 PST 2014
Jan 22 16:17:50 Io kernel: [  159.695466] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: irq 51 for MSI/MSI-X
Jan 22 16:17:50 Io kernel: [  159.700843] NVRM: failed to copy vbios to system memory.
Jan 22 16:17:50 Io kernel: [  159.703143] NVRM: RmInitAdapter failed! (0x30:0xffffffff:720)
Jan 22 16:17:50 Io kernel: [  159.703148] NVRM: rm_init_adapter failed for device bearing minor number 0
Jan 22 16:17:50 Io kernel: [  159.703165] NVRM: nvidia_frontend_open: minor 0, module->open() failed, error -5
Jan 22 16:19:25 Io kernel: [  253.931260] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: irq 51 for MSI/MSI-X
Jan 22 16:19:25 Io kernel: [  253.936524] NVRM: failed to copy vbios to system memory.
Jan 22 16:19:25 Io kernel: [  253.938816] NVRM: RmInitAdapter failed! (0x30:0xffffffff:720)
Jan 22 16:19:25 Io kernel: [  253.938822] NVRM: rm_init_adapter failed for device bearing minor number 0
Jan 22 16:19:25 Io kernel: [  253.938840] NVRM: nvidia_frontend_open: minor 0, module->open() failed, error -5
```

**Xorg.8.log**

```
[   253.727] 
X.Org X Server 1.14.5
Release Date: 2013-12-12
[   253.727] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   253.727] Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-54-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[   253.727] Current Operating System: Linux Io 3.13.0-4-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 16 18:10:11 UTC 2014 x86_64
[   253.727] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-4-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=5b9b1a5b-a812-4478-9e57-49679c2d4cfa ro acpi=force quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[   253.727] Build Date: 15 December 2013  09:53:45PM
[   253.727] xorg-server 2:1.14.5-1ubuntu2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[   253.727] Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
[   253.727]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   253.727] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   253.727] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.8.log", Time: Wed Jan 22 16:19:24 2014
[   253.728] (++) Using config file: "/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia"
[   253.728] (++) Using config directory: "/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.d"
[   253.728] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   253.728] (==) ServerLayout "Layout0"
[   253.728] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen" (0)
[   253.728] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Configured Monitor"
[   253.729] (**) |   |-->Device "Configured Video Device"
[   253.729] (**) Option "AutoAddDevices" "false"
[   253.729] (**) Option "AutoAddGPU" "false"
[   253.729] (**) Not automatically adding devices
[   253.729] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   253.729] (**) Not automatically adding GPU devices
[   253.729] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[   253.729]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   253.729] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[   253.729]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   253.729] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[   253.729]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   253.729] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[   253.729]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   253.729] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[   253.729]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   253.729] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[   253.729] (++) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/nvidia-331/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[   253.729] (==) |-->Input Device "<default pointer>"
[   253.729] (==) |-->Input Device "<default keyboard>"
[   253.729] (==) The core pointer device wasn't specified explicitly in the layout.
    Using the default mouse configuration.
[   253.729] (==) The core keyboard device wasn't specified explicitly in the layout.
    Using the default keyboard configuration.
[   253.729] (II) Loader magic: 0x7f0ec6fc3d20
[   253.729] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   253.729]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   253.729]    X.Org Video Driver: 14.1
[   253.729]    X.Org XInput driver : 19.1
[   253.729]    X.Org Server Extension : 7.0
[   253.730] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[   253.730] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[   253.730] setversion 1.4 failed
[   253.730] (II) config/udev: Ignoring already known drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[   253.732] (--) PCI:*(0:1:0:0) 10de:0fcd:17aa:3801 rev 161, Mem @ 0xc0000000/16777216, 0x90000000/268435456, 0xa0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x00004000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[   253.732] (II) Open ACPI successful (/var/run/acpid.socket)
[   253.732] Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[   253.732] Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[   253.732] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[   253.732] Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[   253.732] Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[   253.732] Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[   253.732] Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[   253.732] Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[   253.732] Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[   253.732] Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
[   253.732] Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[   253.732] Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[   253.732] Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[   253.732] Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[   253.732] Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[   253.732] Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[   253.732] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[   253.732] Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[   253.732] Initializing built-in extension RECORD
[   253.732] Initializing built-in extension DPMS
[   253.732] Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
[   253.732] Initializing built-in extension XVideo
[   253.732] Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[   253.732] Initializing built-in extension SELinux
[   253.732] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[   253.732] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
[   253.732] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
[   253.732] Initializing built-in extension DRI2
[   253.732] (WW) "glamoregl" will not be loaded unless you've specified it to be loaded elsewhere.
[   253.732] (II) "glx" will be loaded by default.
[   253.732] (WW) "xmir" is not to be loaded by default. Skipping.
[   253.732] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[   253.733] (II) Loading /usr/lib/nvidia-331/xorg/libglx.so
[   253.751] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[   253.751]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[   253.751]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[   253.751] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  331.38  Wed Jan  8 19:10:17 PST 2014
[   253.751] Loading extension GLX
[   253.751] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
[   253.751] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 1
[   253.751] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 2
[   253.751] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 3
[   253.751] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 4
[   253.751] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 5
[   253.751] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 6
[   253.752] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[   253.752] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[   253.752] (II) Loading /usr/lib/nvidia-331/xorg/nvidia_drv.so
[   253.752] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[   253.752]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[   253.752]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   253.752] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[   253.752] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[   253.752] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   253.752]    compiled for 1.14.3, module version = 1.0.10
[   253.752]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   253.752]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[   253.752] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[   253.752] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[   253.752] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   253.752]    compiled for 1.14.3, module version = 2.3.3
[   253.752]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   253.752]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[   253.752] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[   253.752] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[   253.752] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   253.752]    compiled for 1.14.3, module version = 0.8.1
[   253.752]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   253.752]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[   253.752] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[   253.753] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[   253.753] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   253.753]    compiled for 1.14.5, module version = 0.4.4
[   253.753]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   253.753]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[   253.753] (II) LoadModule: "mouse"
[   253.753] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/mouse_drv.so
[   253.753] (II) Module mouse: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   253.753]    compiled for 1.14.3, module version = 1.9.0
[   253.753]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[   253.753]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 19.1
[   253.753] (II) LoadModule: "kbd"
[   253.753] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module kbd
[   253.753] (II) UnloadModule: "kbd"
[   253.753] (II) Unloading kbd
[   253.753] (EE) Failed to load module "kbd" (module does not exist, 0)
[   253.753] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  331.38  Wed Jan  8 18:51:00 PST 2014
[   253.753] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[   253.753] (II) NOUVEAU driver Date:   Thu Nov 7 14:56:48 2013 +1000
[   253.753] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
[   253.753]    RIVA TNT        (NV04)
[   253.753]    RIVA TNT2       (NV05)
[   253.753]    GeForce 256     (NV10)
[   253.753]    GeForce 2       (NV11, NV15)
[   253.753]    GeForce 4MX     (NV17, NV18)
[   253.753]    GeForce 3       (NV20)
[   253.753]    GeForce 4Ti     (NV25, NV28)
[   253.753]    GeForce FX      (NV3x)
[   253.753]    GeForce 6       (NV4x)
[   253.753]    GeForce 7       (G7x)
[   253.753]    GeForce 8       (G8x)
[   253.753]    GeForce GTX 200 (NVA0)
[   253.753]    GeForce GTX 400 (NVC0)
[   253.753] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[   253.753] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[   253.753] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[   253.753] (--) using VT number 7

[   253.753] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[   253.753] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[   253.753] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[   253.754] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   253.754]    compiled for 1.14.5, module version = 1.0.0
[   253.754]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[   253.754] (WW) Unresolved symbol: fbGetGCPrivateKey
[   253.754] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
[   253.754] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
[   253.754] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[   253.754] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   253.754]    compiled for 1.14.5, module version = 1.0.0
[   253.754]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[   253.754] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[   253.754] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[   253.754] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[   253.754] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[   253.754] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[   253.754] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[   253.754] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[   253.754] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[   253.754] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[   253.754] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   253.754]    compiled for 1.14.5, module version = 0.0.2
[   253.754]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[   253.754] (II) NVIDIA(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[   253.754] (==) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[   253.754] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[   253.754] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[   253.754] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[   253.754] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[   253.762] (EE) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Failed to initialize the NVIDIA GPU at PCI:1:0:0.  Please
[   253.762] (EE) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     check your system's kernel log for additional error
[   253.762] (EE) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     messages and refer to Chapter 8: Common Problems in the
[   253.762] (EE) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     README for additional information.
[   253.762] (EE) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Failed to initialize the NVIDIA graphics device!
[   253.762] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failing initialization of X screen 0
[   253.762] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[   253.762] (II) UnloadSubModule: "wfbs"
[   253.762] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fb"
[   253.762] (EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
[   253.762] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[   253.762] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[   253.762] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[   253.762] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.8.log" for additional information.
[   253.762] (EE) 
[   253.762] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Comment: pleas how do i get the nvidia card to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a bit of digging, and found this [helpful forum](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/644906/linux/331-20-on-3-13-rc1-kernel/2/), which got me most of the way to getting it to compile.

But compilation is not enough, and if you want working optimus, you need to apply the [patch described here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/670893/linux/nvidia-331-20-will-not-load-with-kernel-3-13-on-efi-without-csm/)

Though there was a lot of confusing signal reading the forums and it wasn't sure exactly what patches to apply where.

So, for your convenience, I have worked out the patches that are needed from a 'vanilla' nvidia sources checkout, and I have personally tested and verified they work on `Kernel 3.13` with `OpenGL Renderer: GeForce GT 540M/PCIe/SSE2`

### Patch 1.

https://gist.github.com/kentfredric/8667008/raw/69c1ef854abc250f36bd0210e9ecc1dcca2827c3/01_kernel-3.13.patch

This is the patch you've probably already got if you have it compiling correctly, and was lifted from [cvs.rpmfusion.org](http://cvs.rpmfusion.org/viewvc/rpms/nvidia-kmod/devel/nvidia_3.13_kernel.patch?revision=1.2&root=nonfree&view=markup)

### Patch 2.

https://gist.github.com/kentfredric/8667008/raw/ad7bb8d6710a17c0116772aef49af95cade34185/02_kernel_3.13_acpi.patch

This is not a patch I can personally find anywhere, and is something I constructed from the description [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/670893/linux/nvidia-331-20-will-not-load-with-kernel-3-13-on-efi-without-csm/)

The reason it fails without this patch is because the macro `DEVICE_ACPI_HANDLE` is no longer defined, so it falls back to the `#else` condition. Which apparently works for everyone except optimus users.

I've done a little more than the simple recommendation of removing the `DEVICE_` prefix, because I wanted the resulting `c` code to work if I happened to use an older kernel.

So instead,

- If `DEVICE_ACPI_HANDLE` exists ( pre 3.13 ), use that.
- Otherwise see if `ACPI_HANDLE` exists, and try that
- Otherwise do fallback mechanics.

### TL;DR.

1. APPLY PATCH 1
2. APPLY PATCH 2
3. ???
4. Be HAPPY :D