# applications close immediately when running with optirun

Tags: nvidia, bumblebee

When I try to run for example `optirun glxgears` the glxgears window opens and closes immediately. It's the same for any other 3d-accelerated application. `optirun firefox` or `optirun nautilus` work though.

Strangely, everything was running fine until today. I didn't change anything, it just stopped working.

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 with Linux-Kernel 3.13.0 on an MSI-GE40 Notebook with an nVidia GTX 760M graphics card with the "nvidia-331" driver and an Intel Core i7-4702MQ.

Comment: Most likely an upgrade broke stuff. Does any error appears in the terminal?

Comment: If you run `optirun glxspheres` does is not even give you a bug? maybe you should try verbose mode. Check out on IRC and github.

Comment: BTW, why are you running kernel 3.13 on saucy?

Comment: I just changed Bridge from auto to virtualgl in etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf and now it is working again. Very strange... Anyways, Thanks for your efforts

Comment: Chances are you've got a broken nvidia, check dmesg. You may not be actually using your GPU anymore, even though apps are working.

Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/409465/

Answer (score 0):

try `primusrun glxgears`, it need to help.